# Not able to do REPLACE in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
select REPLACE


(workbenchStatsByAgeing, '\\','');
```

Error :  Select is not valid at this position for the server version.

Comment: Your query is missing a `FROM` clause.

Comment: maybe `workbenchStatsByAgeing` is variable rather a column in a table

Comment: workbenchStatsByAgeing  is a Variable.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Please add the relevant parts of your stored procedure (including the create statement) and the call statement as text to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You query is invalid.
You need either a **"FROM"** clause referring to the table that contains the column **workbenchStatsByAgeing** or if you're just testing the function with no particular table, you must replace **workbenchStatsByAgeing** by some hard-coded value.

In summary, you'll need one of the below in order for your query to work:

```
select REPLACE(workbenchStatsByAgeing, '\','') from SOME_TABLE;
```

or

```
select REPLACE('This\ is\ my\ string', '\','');
```

Result of second query:

> This is my string

Comment: workbenchStatsByAgeing is a variable. Inside Stored Procedure it is not working.